# I want to store value by creating object of another class, but its showing null pointer exception

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

```
class Car{
    // Instance variables
    String CarId;
    int CarModel;
    String CarBrand;
    int timeRented;
    boolean flag;
    int userRating;
    
    // GETERS and SETTERS
    public String getCarId() {
        return CarId;
    }
    public void setCarId(String carId) {
        this.CarId = carId;
    }
    public int getCarModel() {
        return CarModel;
    }
    public void setCarModel(int carModel) {
        this.CarModel = carModel;
    }
    public String getCarBrand() {
        return CarBrand;
    }
    public void setCarBrand(String carBrand) {
        this.CarBrand = carBrand;
    }
    public int getTimeRented() {
        return timeRented;
    }
    public void setTimeRented(int timeRented) {
        this.timeRented = timeRented;
    }
    public String isFlag() {
        if(flag) return "Car is not Available";
        else return "Car is Available for renting";
    }
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
    public int getUserRating() {
        return userRating;
    }
    public void setUserRating(int userRating) {
        this.userRating = userRating;
    }
    
    // CONSTRUCTOR 
//      Car(String CarId, int CarModel, String CarBrand, boolean flag, int userRating, int timesRented){
//          this.CarId = CarId;
//          this.CarModel = CarModel;
//          this.CarBrand = CarBrand;
//          this.flag = flag;
//          this.userRating = userRating;
//          this.timeRented = timesRented;      
//      }   
//  
    // To print the car details
    public String toString() {
        return "Car Id is: "+this.CarId+
                "\nCar Model is: "+this.CarModel+
                "\nCar Brand is: "+ this.CarBrand+
                "\nCar is: "+ this.isFlag()+
                "\nCar is rented: "+this.timeRented+" times"+
                "\nUser rating of Car is"+ this.userRating;
    }   
}

class carStore extends Car {

//  carStore(String CarId, int CarModel, String CarBrand, boolean flag, int userRating, int timesRented) {
//      super(CarId, CarModel, CarBrand, flag, userRating, timesRented);
//          car[numCar].CarId = CarId;
//          car[numCar].setCarBrand(CarBrand);
//          car[numCar].setCarModel(CarModel);
//          car[numCar].setFlag(flag);
//          car[numCar].setTimeRented(timesRented);
//          car[numCar].setUserRating(userRating);
//      
//  }
    
    Car car [] ;
    
    //car = new Car(super.CarId, super.CarModel, super.CarBrand, super.flag, super.timeRented, super.userRating);
    //  carStore(String CarId, int CarModel, String CarBrand, boolean flag, int userRating, int timesRented) {
    //      super(CarId, CarModel, CarBrand, flag, userRating, timesRented);
    //}
        
    int numCar = 0; 
    // For adding car to the list of car
    void addCar(String CarId, int CarModel, String CarBrand, boolean flag, int userRating, int timesRented){    
        car[numCar].CarId = CarId;
        car[numCar].setCarBrand(CarBrand);
        car[numCar].setCarModel(CarModel);
        car[numCar].setFlag(flag);
        car[numCar].setTimeRented(timesRented);
        car[numCar].setUserRating(userRating);
        numCar += 1;
    }
    
    // For checking the Availability of the car 
    String checkOut(String carId){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (car[i].CarId == carId) {
              car[i].isFlag();
             }
        }
        return "Car ID deos not Exist";
    }
    
    // For returning of the car
    String returnCar(String carId){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (car[i].CarId == carId) {
              car[i].setFlag(false);
              return "Car returned successfully";
             }
        }
        return "Car ID deos not Exist";
    }
    // Give car a rating
    String recieveRating(String carId, int rating) {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (car[i].CarId == carId) {
              car[i].setUserRating(rating);
              return "Rating given successfully";
             }
            
        }
        return "Car ID deos not Exist";
    }
    // Rent a car based on the car id
    String rentACar(String carId){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (car[i].CarId == carId) {
              car[i].setFlag(true);
              System.out.println("Car Rented Successfully");
             }
        }
        return "Car ID deos not Exist";
    }
    
    // List of the car Store
    void listInventory() {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {            
         System.out.println(car[i].getCarId()+" "+
                            car[i].getCarModel()+" "+
                            car[i].getCarBrand()+" "+
                            car[i].getTimeRented()+" "+
                            car[i].getUserRating()+" "+
                            car[i].isFlag());
         }
    }
    
}


public class CarLauncher {
  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating object of the store
    carStore myCarStore = new carStore();
    // Adding 5 different cars 
    myCarStore.addCar("Abhinav", 2016, "Huyndai", false, 4, 10);
    myCarStore.addCar("Nipun", 2017, "Baleno", false, 5, 3);
    myCarStore.addCar("Nakul", 2020, "BMW", false, 5, 12);
    myCarStore.addCar("Abhishek", 2013, "Audi", false, 4, 6);
    myCarStore.addCar("Nipun", 2016, "Huyndai", false, 4, 7);
    
    //myCarStore.listInventory();
    
  }
   
}
```

In this code I want to add 5 cars by add method of the carStore class but its throwing null pointer exception saying this.car is null. Can anyone tell me why the add method is not adding values in the car object and its throwing the following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at carStore.addCar(CarLauncher.java:94)
at CarLauncher.main(CarLauncher.java:166)
```

Comment: You should initilaze the Car car[] before using it. I recommend to use List instead of Array if the number of cars is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `Car car[]` is not initialized. You must define it a size:

```
Car car[] = new Car[yourSize];
```

And then, when you call to the `addCar` method, you have to instance the current position:

```
 void addCar(String CarId, int CarModel, String CarBrand, boolean flag, int userRating, int timesRented)
{

 if(numCar < car.length)
    {
        car[numCar] = new Car();
        car[numCar].CarId = CarId;
        car[numCar].setCarBrand(CarBrand);
        car[numCar].setCarModel(CarModel);
        car[numCar].setFlag(flag);
        car[numCar].setTimeRented(timesRented);
        car[numCar].setUserRating(userRating);
        numCar += 1;
    }
}
```

With the if condition you will avoid an Exception, because your array has a size that you define before. So, you have to check always if the current index it's not out of size.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your car array is not initialized. That's why you got a `null pointer exception`. By initializing you can solve the issue.

Moreover suggest some improvement.

1. Rename **carStore** to **CarStore**. Java class name should start with a capital letter.

`class CarStore extends Car`

2. Avoid array `Car car []` in this scenario. Use arraylist `List<Car> carList`.
3. Create `CarStore` constructor. Inside this initialize `carList`

```
public CarStore(){
   List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>(); 
}
```

4. Modify `addCar` method. Add `new car` into `carList` here.

```
public void addCar(Car car){
   carList.add(car);
}
```

5. Modify the rest of the code in this manner.

It improves readability and organizes your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your Array is not initialized.try to initialized the array Car car[]

Comment: Yess sir but it is not the real issue